# data domain not found error in production

Tags: amadeus

I just deployed an app in production and using the inspiration flight search for european airport return a "DATA DOMAIN NOT FOUND FOR REQUEST" error. all the countries aren't available in this API ?

Here is a list of the airport that return error

```
LIL
CDG
BRU
EIN
CRL
OST
RTM
ANR
SEN
```

Comment: So what did you try that worked? I suppose you use `/shopping/flight-destinations?origin=CDG` which fails. Since Amadeus is based in France, I don't think that country specific availability is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Flight Inspiration Search and Flight Cheapest Date Search APIs are "inspirational APIs" built on a pre-computed cache. This cache has a limited number of origin-destination and do not cover all possibles cities, for this you will need to use the Flight Offers Search API.

We are working to increase the data coverage of those 2 APIs to offers more and better data.

Note: The API works with city IATA code and not airport (NYC for New-York and not JFK / PAR for Paris and not CDG)